# Control verbosity level of WP DEBUG?

Tags: debug, wp-config, configuration, wp-debug, logging

I've been at a loss so far and so I thought I'd pose the question: Is there a way to modify the verbosity level of the WP `debug.log` via `wp-config.php` or elsewhere?

Just an fyi, here is what I have in my `wp-config.php` to enable logging:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEBUG

 // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);

// END DEBUG
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `WP_DEBUG` is set, WordPress sets (via [`wp_debug_mode()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_debug_mode/) call early in core load process) the [error reporting level](http://www.php.net/error-reporting) to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`. This means all warnings and errors except strict errors and PHP deprecated functions (not WordPress ones).

You can define your own level in a custom [mu-plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) (the override needs to be called as soon as possible, but after WordPress core load). Use [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) for information about the error levels you can use. An example:

```
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE );
```